# Data Grid View Replace Value

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, replace

Can you help me with this..

```
   For Each r As DataGridViewRow In dglist.Rows
        For Each c As DataGridViewCell In r.Cells
            If c.Value IsNot Nothing Then
                **If c.Value.ToString = Label2.Text.ToString Then
                    c.Value.ToString.Trim.Replace(c.Value.ToString.Trim, TextBox1.Text)
                End If**

                'MessageBox.Show(c.Value.ToString)
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

I need to replace the value of the cell with the value of the label.
But still my code did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the value (to cell value property) rather than operate on the value of string you have. When you do an operation like `ToString` etc an additional instance in memory is created and that's all if you are not assigning it. Do this instead:

```
 For Each r As DataGridViewRow In dglist.Rows
        For Each c As DataGridViewCell In r.Cells
            If c.Value IsNot Nothing Then
                **If c.Value.ToString = Label2.Text Then
                    c.Value = TextBox1.Text
                End If**

                'MessageBox.Show(c.Value.ToString)
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Reconsider your if clauses since I am not very sure that's what you are looking for. In your question you say you want to assign the value of label, but in the code you pasted it seemed to me that you are after text value of your text box.

Comment: now my problem is how can I update my database, now I change my datagridview

Comment: @kelvzy that's entirely a different question. If you are facing some trouble, then please make it another question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116407/sql-edit-cell-in-datagridview-and-save
I already did but nobody answer it :( title: SQL Edit Cell in DataGridView and Save